# flutter observable widget and refreshing widget state

Tags: flutter, widget, observable, refresh, flutter-getx

Can someone help me to refresh card slider widget when added new card. I tried to use obx widget but something went wrong and got error. then i tried to refresh a text widget when added a new card but i couldn't refresh the text.

**I want to make changes on this screen with Obx() widget.**

I put some .obs variables but app not watching this variables.
here i am sharing repository branch to yours to see project.

Comment: Please add the code here. Dont give repo link

Comment: If you are using getx then always update your MaterialApp to GetMaterialApp

Comment: not pasted code because I have too long code and i dont know where is the wrong line. there is a problem about whole project.

Comment: I updated MaterialApp to GetMaterialApp but still not refreshing.

Comment: Because nothing changes on list even i watched the observable data.  So i want to refresh card list widget but using already old data. actually i need to refresh my list before everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to fix it: Already using stateful widget so if we want to refresh widget after get back to previous widget we put then function after MaterialPageRoute function.